# Integrating a javascript framework into Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, chromium

Browsing github I stumbled upon [this](https://github.com/polygonplanet/chillout), and reading the description it says there

> You can use it in any JavaScript environment (**Browser**, Electron, Node.js).

Now this got me curious. How do I integrate it into my Chrome browser? If such a thing is even possible.

Comment: https://tampermonkey.net/?

Comment: Yea...I'm lost. Elaborate please?

Comment: Read the link. It allows you to add scripts to your browser.